# Android: Using a webview similar solution inside service?

Tags: android, web, webview

I would like to use a browser in the service. The loaded page has javascript, redirections, input parameters, cookies etc. Difficult enough
I know webview can be used only in Activity. But is there any solution instead of webview????
Thanks

ps: i've tried to replace my working solution (in activity) with post/get/cookie management but wasn't successful

Launching an activity (even it's invisible) is not a solution bacause it stops the running activity.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution since then? I am looking for a similar solution. I actually don't mind stopping the running activity, I only need it to be **invisible**. Is it possible to make WebView invisible? or transparent?

Answer (score 0):

As per Googles recommendation, service must only create notifications. From notification you can then launch an activity.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Notifications

Comment: Not really answering the question since the OP stated *"Launching an activity (even it's invisible) is not a solution bacause it stops the running activity."*.